# "message": "(#294) Managing advertisements requires an acess token with the extended permission for ads_management"

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to test my server to server app and my app is an website. But the calls to the marketing API are done from my node js server. I am able to create campaigns and Adsets, but not the Ads. when I try, I'm reciving this error message on marketing api calls to create Ads:
"message": "(#294) Managing advertisements requires an acess token with the extended permission for ads_management".

The thing is, I have already been approved to use ads_management, but when I try to set my app to public, so I can create Ads, the "Generate Token" tool of my app become disabled.

I have also asked permission to use Api Standard Access mode (instead of development mode), but it was denied due to unsuccessful api calls. But how can I have successful api calls if I can't generate an access token with ads_managment permissions, neither can I create Ads while in development mode?

Comment: What do you mean by, _“the "Generate Token" tool of my app become disabled”_? Are you referring to the Graph API Explorer or something, did you not implement login within your app itself?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?